# Pulling dependencies using YARN from private registry artifactory

Tags: reactjs, https, npm-install, artifactory, yarnpkg

The team I am working on we are developing React applications and we are using yarn for pulling dependencies. We are using a private registry from where we are pulling npm dependencies and we are also using a private artifactory via jFrog to pull and publish common components like buttons, plots etc.

So far with the private registry we do not experience any problem while we were working with yarn. We used npmrc file locally on our repository to setup the registry from where we are pulling dependencies.

Now we have to add a scoped registry pointing to our private artifactory. So my npmrc file looks like that:

```
registry=http://private-registry/npmjs-group/
loglevel=http
strict-ssl=false

@scoped-name:registry=https://private.artifactory.com/artifactory/api/npm/shared-components
```

So, when I am using npm install the dependencies coming from artifactory are fetched behind **http** `http://private.artifactory.com/artifactory/api/npm/shared-components`

However, when I am using yarn install with the previous npmrc I get the following:

```
info There appears to be trouble with your network connection. Retrying...
error An unexpected error occurred: "http://private.artifactory.com/artifactory/api/npm/shared-components/@scopred-name/icons-0.1.0.tgz: connect ETIMEDOUT 146.106.239.15:80".
```

I tried to set up proxy,https-proxy config setting on npmrc but I could not make it to work. I did something like that:

```
proxy=http://private.artifactory.com/artifactory/api/npm/shared-components
https-proxy=http://private.artifactory.com/artifactory/api/npm/shared-components
```

I am not sure if those settings are appropriate. Or is another issue.
I tried the same approach with the same failing results by using yarnrc.

In addition, I saw this open issue on jFrog https://www.jfrog.com/jira/browse/RTFACT-12703. 
It seems that jFrog is not supporting YARN is it true?

I would be really appreciated if someone from the open community can give some light here.